# The explaination of definition of learning

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, behaviorism, psychology, behavior

In Robert Baron's book I found learning to be "any permanent change in behaviour or behavioural potential as a result of experiences. (Bandura,1986).But I got a question that what is meant by- RELATIVELY PERMANENT ....

I think it means that the changed behaviour should last for a relatively longer period , but "relative to what" , so it looks like an ambiguity thers and not like a specific testable or scientific definition...
Can anyone supply me some clarification over this definition or
Some more specific definition along with author and date please...As it should be with the definition in my exam my lecturer has given this definition without any clarification

Also books give only what I have written without specifying the permanence in explaination ... please help or mention any source for it..

Comment: Could you provide a link to the author's comment? A sentence out of context is hard to interpret.  An excerpt of the section may help too. I can say that learning something does not last a lifetime. Motor learning can be pretty permanent, but information, like textbook material can fade quickly. Hence, it's relative.